# Comparing cell with a table before copying the row to the table from another table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm trying to compare the second cell from a row with the second cell of all rows in a table before copying the row to the table from another table using jQuery. But I cannot figure out the condition clause. This is what i have:

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on("click","#submit",function(){
    var getSelectedRows = $("#schedule input:checked").parents("tr").clone();
    if ($('#results').find("tr").filter(":contains('$('td:first', $(this).parents('tr')).text()')"))
      alert("You can't have two events at the same time!");
    else
      $("#results tbody").append(getSelectedRows);
  })
})
```

I have this html:

```
<table id="schedule" class="table table-stripped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>time</th>
      <th>room</th>
      <th>presenter</th>
      <th>title</th>
      <th>detail</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="yes"></td>
      <td>9:00am</td>
      <td>SE135</td>
      <td>aaaaa</td>
      <td>aaaaaa</td>
      <td>aaaaaaaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="yes"></td>
      <td>9:00am</td>
      <td>SE145</td>
      <td>aaaaab</td>
      <td>aaaaaa</td>
      <td>aaaaaaaa</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
</article>
<table id="results">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>time</th>
      <th>room</th>
      <th>presenter</th>
      <th>title</th>
      <th>detail</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: i figured that i was trying to compare to the first in the script, but i still cannot figure it out.

Comment: Show sample html as per [mcve]. Your `:contains` won't work for several reasons... improper/msimatched quotes and invalid concatenation. Note errors thrown in your browser console

Comment: @charlietfl I have added the html. I did not know about those limitation of using :contains  thank you.

Comment: Whole thing would be much simpler if you just add a`selected` class to the rows in main table when you create clone. Then ignore that class when looking for checked inputs

Comment: ALso important to understand that `$(selector).filter()` returns an object even if no matches are found. `if(Object)` is always truthy. For jQuery object use `if( $(selector).filter().length )`. When no elements match the length is zero which is falsy

Comment: @charlietfl yea but i still need to compare to it because i  need the second cell element to be different than a row that's already in the second table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to loop through all instances of  selected rows and compare each row to the existing ones in results table.

I would do this in opposite process flow....collect an array of the values that already exist in results...then as you loop through the checked rows in main table compare that value to the array.

Note that the addition of common classes and `data-` attributes can help simplify things also

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "#submit", function() {
    var $resBody = $('#results tbody'),
      // create array of rooms already in results
      existingRooms = $resBody.find('tr[data-room]').map(function() {
        return $(this).data('room')
      }).get();
    // log array for demo purposes
    console.log('existingRooms', JSON.stringify(existingRooms));
    
    // now loop through the selected checkboxes
    $("#schedule input:checked").each(function() {
      var $row = $(this).closest('tr'),
        room = $row.data('room');
      // is current room instance already in array?
      if ($.inArray(room, existingRooms) === -1) {
        $resBody.append($row.clone());
      } else {
        alert("Room " + room +' already selected');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="schedule" class="table table-stripped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>time</th>
      <th>room</th>
      <th>presenter</th>
      <th>title</th>
      <th>detail</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-room="SE135">
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="yes"></td>
      <td>9:00am</td>
      <td class="room">SE135</td>
      <td>aaaaa</td>
      <td>aaaaaa</td>
      <td>aaaaaaaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-room="SE145">
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="yes" checked></td>
      <td>9:00am</td>
      <td class="room">SE145</td>
      <td>aaaaab</td>
      <td>aaaaaa</td>
      <td>aaaaaaaa</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">

<table id="results">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>time</th>
      <th>room</th>
      <th>presenter</th>
      <th>title</th>
      <th>detail</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: wow! thank you so much! this is exactly what i needed. i learnt so much!